# T-SQL parse 5 comma-delimited strings into a table efficiently

Tags: arrays, string, t-sql, csv

I've wandered through a number of ways to cobble this together, but need advice on the most performant way to accomplish my task.

I'm writing a procedure that's passed 5 variables from a front end.  Each variable is a varchar of up to 3118 comma-separated elements.  I need these pivoted into a table and returned in a highly efficient manner.

I have found parsing routines, and pivoting methods, and methods that use CTEs and temp tables and table variables.

The example below is just an illustration - in real life, these strings can get pretty long.  So I'm hoping to avoid lengthy experimentation and see if you guys can point me at the BEST way to handle the challenge.

--***
-- starting with this:

```
declare @decimal varchar(50), @binary varchar(50), @primes varchar(50), @hex varchar(50), var5 varchar(50)

set @decimal = '1,2,3,4,5'
set @binary = '1,2,4,8,16'
set @primes = '1,2,3,5,7,11'
set @hex = '1','16','256','4096'
set @ancient = 'one','two','many'
```

-- create an output table that will look like this:

```
declare @results table (id int identity(1,1),  [integer] varchar(1), [binary] varchar(1), prime varchar(50), hex varchar(50), ancient varchar (50))

id  integer  binary  prime  hex    ancient
1   1        1       1      1      one
2   2        2       2      16     two
3   3        4       3      256    many
4   4        8       5      4096   null
5   5        16      7      null   null
6   null     null    11     null   null
```

--***

Answer (score 2):

I would use an XML parameter that looks like this.

```
<r>
  <i>1</i>
  <b>1</b>    
  <p>1</p>
  <h>1</h>
  <a>one</a>
</r>
<r>
  <i>2</i>
  <b>2</b>    
  <p>2</p>
  <h>16</h>
  <a>two</a>
</r>
```

And insert to the table variable like this.

```
insert into @results([integer], [binary], prime, hex, ancient)
select T.N.value('i[1]', 'varchar(1)'),
       T.N.value('b[1]', 'varchar(1)'),
       T.N.value('p[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       T.N.value('h[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       T.N.value('a[1]', 'varchar(50)')
from @xml.nodes('/r') as T(N)
```

In my experience this is efficient enough. From SQL Server 2008 you could use a [Table-Valued Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead. I have not used that so I can't tell you if it performs any better.

Comment: Great idea and useful code.  I can't change the way the front end passes the strings, but I'll keep this for future use!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You maybe could consider calling an assembly doing this parsing for you.
Here is a [tutorial](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-clr-stored-procedures-in-charp-introduction-to-charp-part-1), some [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx) and another example [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/)